# How to enable the DAPM widgets manually in ALSA?

Tags: linux-kernel, alsa, power-management

How to enable the DAPM widgets manually in ALSA?

Like writing something into somewhere should enable that DAPM widget and it related calls into the codec driver should happen.

Is there anything that we can do like this?

Eg:
For gpio stuff we can write something into some debugfs files and can control the gpio.

I am looking for something like this in ALSA DAPM

Note: I know setting the mixer controls and completing the path can power up the widgets